# G/N is abelian for normal groups of a normal group N where centralizer is in N

Tags: group-theory

Let N be normal in G such that every subgroup of N is normal in G and $C_{G}(N) \subseteq N$. Prove G/N is abelian.

A proof that I am going for looks like this:

Let $U \subseteq N$. Then, for some a,b in U,

$aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$

$ab(ba)^{-1} \in N$ (socks and shoes property)

$(ab)(ba)^{-1} \in N$

$Nab=Nba$ *I do not understand this line. Where does it come from and why use it?* I think it has to do with N being normal...?

And finally, $(Na)(Nb)=(Nb)(Na)$ so $G/N$ is abelian. (Why are we able to do this commuatativity here?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first concern:

$N(ab) = N(ba)$ because of the previous line. It is a theorem that if $x^{-1}y \in H$, then $xH = yH$.

For the second:

$(Na)(Nb) = N(ab) = N(ba)$ because we just proved that above!

Comment: Oh, ok so it was definitely the missing theorem that threw me off and my understanding (lack-thereof) of the notation. Thanks for clarifying!